# Inserting Related list into a custom display form

Tags: custom-form, related-list

I have a contacts list and a leave calendar list, there's a look up field on the leave calendar to select the name of the person going on leave, then I use that field to insert a related list web part on to the display form of the contacts list - basically so that if someone clicks on the contact they can see upcoming/current leave.

This works perfectly in the default dispform.aspx but I can't get it to work in a custom form, I'd prefer a custom form since dispform.aspx is not very user friendly and not mobile response.

I can insert the leave calendar list but when I try to add a connection I get the error "No Consumer Schema".

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? SharePoint 2010/2013/2016 on premise or SharePoint Online

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 on premise